# Handing 2D-Array from Spring boot to React

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, reactjs, spring-boot

I am trying to send a 2D Char-Array from my Spring-Controller to React ... it works when i use Arraylist but doesn't work with "char[ ][ ]"

so this works

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test")
public ArrayList<String> getTest() {

    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    arr.add("Something");
    arr.add("Somehow");
    return arr;
```

and this Does not work

```
@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:WhitespaceAround")
@GetMapping(value = "/newboard")
public char[][] emptyBoard(char[][] playField) {

    for (char y = 0; y < playField.length; y++) {

        for (char x = 0; x < playField[y].length; x++) {

            playField[y][x] = (' ');

        }
    }
        return playField;
}
```

Comment: uhm what about using `List<List< Character >>`

Comment: I'm trying to use a better and more simple approach, because i don't want to change all the methods in my code... since they all uses "playField as char[][]" @AlbertoSinigaglia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good research i found that it doesn't work sending primitive datatype to Frontend... this is as Answer to this question not all the situations maybe, but at least in my case that was the solution.

you have to try the following:

Either try the Refernce types =>

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test")
public ArrayList<String> getTest() {

ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
arr.add("Something");
arr.add("Somehow");
return arr;
```

OR this approach (From type {Class} ) =>

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/test")
 public MyModel getTest() {


    MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
    myModel.setFirstName("Somthing");
    myModel.setLastName("Somehow");

    GameUpdate u = new GameUpdate();
    Player p1 = new Player();
    p1.setName("1");
    u.setPlayer1(p1);
    return myModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the return type, and so "cast" the return object:

```
@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:WhitespaceAround")
@GetMapping(value = "/newboard")
public List<List<Character>> emptyBoard(char[][] playField) {

    for (char y = 0; y < playField.length; y++) {

        for (char x = 0; x < playField[y].length; x++) {

            playField[y][x] = (' ');

        }
    }
    return Arrays.asList(playField)
                .stream()
                .map(Arrays::asList)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but => "List<List<Character>>" this aproach looks like the same as (Arraylist<Arraylist<char[]>>)... your solution maybe usefull but i need to change the variable (playField) in all the methods i used, and that will cause a lot of problem in my game Algorithm.

Comment: @BasharBoutros no you don't need to change anything, you will need to change only the return statement on the Controller class where you are returning the matrix

Comment: i got this error

java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method asList()
  location: class java.util.stream.Collectors

Comment: @BasharBoutros sorry, just a typo, try now